# Impact of Basis Transition on Vector Magnitudes

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

## Effect of Basis Change on Vector Lengths in Different Vector Spaces

### Does a change in the vector space of a matrix affect the length of vectors?

For instance, if in basis B, $$[v_1]_B = 3[v_2]_B$$, would it be possible in basis C for $$[v_1]_C ≠ 3[v_2]_C$$
for example:
$$[v_1]_C = 4[v_2]_C$$
given that B and C span the same vector space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basis change doesn't change length ratios. If $M$ is the matrix for basis change from $B$ to $C$, i.e. $[v]_C=M[v]_B$, then we have:
$$[v_1]_C = M[v_1]_B = M\cdot 3[v_2]_B = 3\cdot M[v_2]_B=3[v_2]_C \ .$$

In general, if $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $[v_1]_B=\lambda [v_2]_B$,  we have:
$$[v_1]_C = M[v_1]_B = M\cdot \lambda[v_2]_B = \lambda \cdot M[v_2]_B=\lambda[v_2]_C \ .$$

Comment: How do I prove that? for every /lambda from the field?

Comment: @fatFeather yes, of course this holds for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, I added it to the answer for completeness